# Left join a subset of TableA with TableB, but keeping all of the rows from TableA

Tags: sql, presto

I have two tables, `TableA` and `TableB`, where `TableB` has extra data about rows in `TableA` but only when `TableA.type IN (2, 3)`. If I do something like

```sql
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.type,
    b.*
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
ON a.id = b.id
    AND a.type IN (2, 3)
WHERE a.dt = '2022-02-03'
    AND b.dt = '2022-02-03'
```

it would only return rows where `type` is 2 or 3. However, I want to return all of the rows `TableA`, even when the type isn't 2 or 3. I expect the columns from `b.*` to be `NULL` when the `type` doesn't match.

One idea I was thinking of is to UNION this query with a separate query which manually selects null for all of `TableB`'s columns and checking if the `type` isn't 2 or 3, but that seems pretty tedious. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

For example, `TableA`:

| dt | id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '2022-02-03' | 1 | 2 |
| '2022-02-03' | 2 | 3 |
| '2022-02-03' | 3 | 1 |
| '2022-02-03' | 1 | 1 |

and `TableB`:

| dt | id | col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '2022-02-03' | 1 | true |
| '2022-02-03' | 2 | false |
| '2022-02-03' | 3 | true |

My query would return a table like

| id | type | dt | col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | '2022-02-03' | true |
| 2 | 3 | '2022-02-03' | false |

but I would want the rest of the rows in `TableA` as well

| id | type | dt | col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | '2022-02-03' | true |
| 2 | 3 | '2022-02-03' | false |
| 3 | 1 | '2022-02-03' | null |
| 1 | 1 | '2022-02-03' | null |

Comment: Why do you add that a.type IN (2, 3) condition? (As you say _TableB has extra data about rows in TableA but only when TableA.type IN (2, 3)_.)

Comment: It's possible that there are ids in `TableA` and `TableB` that match even when the type is wrong. The rows in TableB only apply when the type is correct.

Comment: Show us some sample table data, and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) [mcve]

Comment: You have no `WHERE` clause at all, so all the rows  of `TableA`  will be returned by  `.. TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB ..`

Comment: Which version of presto are you using? Works fine for me in Athena v2.

Comment: The `and a.type in ...`  as part of the ON clause only affects the join, it does not constrain rows coming from tablea.

Comment: @Serg You're right. I did have a WHERE clause but I omitted it because I thought it wouldn't matter. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, the issue was that I put some conditions in the WHERE clause rather than in the join condition. If I amend my query to something like

```sql
SELECT
    b.*,
    a.dt,
    a.id,
    a.type
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
ON a.id = b.id
    AND a.type IN (2, 3)
    AND a.dt = '2022-02-03'
    AND b.dt = '2022-02-03'
```

I get the results that I want.